# Google analytics - _trackEvent before _setAccount? Does order matter?

Tags: google-analytics

So this will work:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

---

**But what if the visitor can come by a link like `http://example.com?autoPlay=Wind`?** So then the video is already requested, and starts playing, generating:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

event. But then the regular tracking code still runs at the bottom of the page, that's why we have async for:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

So do I have to move at least the `_setAccount` to the top, or will it just work as it's already in the queue by the time I call `ga.js`? Or I could just make my own queue... But here I see a clue that [they made sure](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push) not to delete `_gaq` if something is already in it even before `_setAccount`. And also there are multiple trackers for different contexts... **So does this mean it's perfectly legal to ignore the order altogether?** Sorry for the simple question, but I can found exactly nothing on what is allowed with async and what is not.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got to have the `_setAccount` before any commands that log data, like `_trackPageview` or `_trackEvent`.

If you look at the tracking pixel that's sent by `_trackEvent` when `_setAccount` hasn't run yet, you'll see that it logs to a default account, something like `UA-XXXXX-X`.

I've used this on development or staging systems where I want the analytics code to run, but don't want it to pollute production tracking data. Comment out the `_setAccount` line, and all data ends up logged to a non-existent account.

---

Assuming you never initialized a tracker named 'mumble' (with `_gaq.push(['mumble._setAccount', 'UA-65432-1'])`, the following code shows the ID of an uninitiated tracker is 'UA-XXXXX-X':

```
echo(_gat.getTrackerByName('mumble')_getAccount())
```

Comment: "Comment out the _setAccount line, and all data ends up logged to a non-existent account." -- Can't believe I didn't know this!

Comment: Comment out: Yes, if you don't give it the account, how could it log onto it?
But better: Move it one line lower, and you won't even notice in your code something is missing.

Comment: @ZoltánMorvai: the account ID ends up as one of the parameters of any tracking pixels sent -- there's no logging in involved while tracking.

Answer (score 2):

Now it does:

```js
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
if(_gaq.unshift){
    _gaq.unshift(['_setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
} else {
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-65432-1']);
}
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

So the solution is that while `push` appends to the end of the array, while `unshift` does so to the beginning.

The problem can be that in case of an iframe *ga* is already loaded, and then it's not an array, but an object with a custom `push` method. In that case let's just fall back to the original code. Within your own homepage the account id was the same, and it works anyway.